# How can I copy all built files from one referenced project to a subfolder of another?

Tags: msbuild

Given a target like this:

```
<Target Name="CopyLegacyServer" BeforeTargets="AfterBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="..\Legacy\Legacy.csproj" BuildInParallel="$(BuildInParallel)" Targets="Build">
        <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="CopyLegacyServerOutput" />
    </MSBuild>

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(CopyLegacyServerOutput)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\test" />

</Target>
```

How can I copy all built files from the CopyLegacyServerOutput directory, instead of just the entry assembly/exe?

My goal is to reference a project, but have all the output files from that project located in a subfolder in the output of the referencing project. The referenced project is an old console app, that is started from within the referencing project - and it is all copied to a final output directory, and that creates problems with different versions of dependencies.

Comment: The `TargetOutputs` parameter of the `MSBuild` task will only provide the primary "target" file - `Legacy.exe`. I would remove the `MSBuild` task in the `CopyLegacyServer` target. It doesn't help. Are you using a solution file? Is the 'Legacy' project in the solution? I would use the solution file and set a build order dependency that 'Legacy' must be built before the referencing project. In `CopyLegacyServer` copy from the appropriate folder based on the current `$(Configuration)`.

Comment: @JonathanDodds Thanks, that could work! I wonder if I can get the directory part of the path from the TargetOutputs... that way I won't have to "hide the dependency" away in the solution file.

Comment: I assume you are not using a `ProjectReference` because the `Legacy` project is an .exe and not a .dll. You could use `<ProjectReference  Include="..\Legacy\Legacy.csproj" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false">`. This would show the project dependency in the project.

Comment: One thing to consider is that you may get a quicker build if you don't use an `MSBuild` task. The referencing project has to pause and wait for the `MSBuild` task to complete. (The `BuildInParallel` attribute to the `MSBuild` task applies to the projects specified in the `Projects` attribute - which in this case is one project.) By using the `MSBuild` task you are hiding the dependency from the MSBuild schedular. MSBuild will know about the `Legacy` project up front if a `ProjectReference` and/or a solution build order dependency is used.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I have a version where I use a ProjectReference, but I still need to have the files copied to a subdir instead in the consuming project? Is there a good way to do that for project references?

Comment: Are you asking if a [`ProjectReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022#projectreference) can be defined to copy the referenced assembly to a different location? No, it can't but it may be possible to do something clever with the `Targets` metadata.

Comment: @JonathanDodds thanks, I'm trying to wrap my head around that :) Right now I'm trying `ProjectReference` with `ReferenceOutputAssembly` set to false and try to just get the folder name where the reference was built to, so I can copy the entire folder. Any hints are appreciated :)

Comment: An MSBuild project is a set of instructions for how to build, but it doesn't have 'state' or 'history'. You can't query a project about how it built previously or how it might build in the future. You could assume that the referenced project has the same definition of `OutputPath` as the referencing project - i.e. `bin\$(Configuration)` for legacy style projects or `bin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)` for SDK style. Or you could customize the referenced project to add a target that will write the last used `OutputPath` to a file

Comment: Thanks! I now ended up setting `OutDir` for the referenced project, so I know where to get the files regardless of configuration and platform - as they are not the same as for the consuming project (which is kind of the root of the problem). Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @JonathanDodds and to make it actually work, it is now a combination of setting `OutDir` in referenced projects, reference the project with `ReferenceOutputAssebly=false` and adding the referenced project's output as `Content` to the consuming project.